# 'npm update check failed' on W10, no .config file exists

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm on Windows 10. Whenever I do an npm command (version 5.8.0), I get :

```
npm update check failed                    
Try running with sudo or get access              
to the local update config store via             
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\<my user folder>\.config
```

Now I would have gladly looked into permissions issues to .config, but :

- I am running the cmd in admin mode
- I don't have any .config **anywhere**

How would you go about fixing this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

first of all uninstall nodejs and again install nodejs
anf still if problem is not gone then follow the following steps

now Go to C:\Users\vishwajeet.config\configstore` (here 'vishwajeet' is my account name)

In `\configstore`, there will be `update-notifier-npm` json file. Open this file with any editor and if you can see the following data:

{
    "optOut": false,
    "lastUpdateCheck": 1552087604401
}

Replace the value of `optOut` to "true" if it is "false". This will remove the error of npm update check failed!

Answer (score 2):

I already had a `.config` file in `C:\Users\<username>\` which prevented npm to create its own .config file.
Deleting .config file solved the issue for me.