# issue in npm update check failed

Tags: npm, npm-update

```
 npm update check failed                     
             Try running with sudo or get access               
             to the local update config store via              
 sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Rahul Raj\.config
```

Please  explain me in a step by step so that I will easily understand.  I am windows 10 user

Comment: Have you tried something? Does that config exist? Are rights ok?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558537/npm-update-check-failed-on-w10-no-config-file-exists